# Receiving "DataReader.GetFieldType returned null." error.

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, geospatial, spatial

I have designed a windows form application with a .NET 4.5 target.  I am trying to install the program on a couple of co worker's systems and keep receiving the same error on both systems.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: DataReader.GetFieldType(60) returned null.
```

This program basically retrieves data from a database and stores them in an excel file.  It performs some calculations on the data, but nothing with the **geometry type** column except for retrieving it.

-I have tried installing **ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi** and **ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi** on the target systems.

-I have tried referencing **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types** and including the DLL in the files

-I have tried referencing **SqlServerSpatial.DLL** and **SqlServerSpatial100.DLL** but it does not let me add the references.

I am now having trouble finding other resources to try.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks ahead.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?  If not, I think I will just omit the geometry from the excel file.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: No I did not, I ended up omitting the geometry column because we didn't need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to finally get this working by adding a reference to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
```

and setting Copy Local to true.  Odd that the nuget package worked for me in a different project, but not this one.  Anyway, hope this helps somebody!

Comment: I believe the correct path is:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies`